# d3 + react-faux-dom, not rendering any data with .data().enter

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to integrate d3 with react by using react-faux-dom, but I can't see anything on the browser. I can see in react developer tool the right nodes are being rendered but no data is visible. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Below is a simple example of what I am doing.

```
class Test extends React.Component {


 render(){
    const w = window.innerWidth;
    const h = window.innerHeight;

    const dataset = [ 25, 7, 5, 26, 11, 8, 25, 14, 23, 19,
                   14, 11, 22, 29, 11, 13, 12, 17, 18, 10,
                   24, 18, 25, 9, 3 ];

// append the svg canvas to the page
    let someDiv = d3.select(ReactFauxDOM.createElement('div'))
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h)
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "node")


      someDiv.selectAll(".node")
      .data(dataset)  // <-- The answer is here!
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("height", function(d) {
          var barHeight = d * 5;
          return barHeight + "px";
      })
      .style("color", "red")
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>render</h3>
           <div>
            {someDiv.node().toReact()}
          </div>
        </div>
       )
      }
    }

export default Test
```

When I check the react dev tool, I can see nodes being rendered but can't see anything on the browser: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select all `.node` will return nothing as they enter append is not appending elements with the class `node`.

```
someDiv.selectAll(".node")
      .data(dataset)  // <-- The answer is here!
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "bar")
```

This should fix it, as you are appending `divs` with the class `bar`.

```
someDiv.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(dataset)  // <-- The answer is here!
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "bar")
```

[Example block where each appended div is a different color.](http://blockbuilder.org/pmkroeker/76320ddb5621b446957f8ef7ec940e70)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't fix it. I nothing has changed on the browser or on the console.

Comment: A note while I continue to look, try adding a background color to the appended divs to see if they are being rendered but are just white.

Comment: @Kimmiekim I added a full example where I changed the backgrounds of the appended divs. I did strip out the react part, but that didn't seem to cause issues with your code.

Comment: oh yea i can see the colors now. I guess it was just rendering in blank color. But isn't the whole point of using d3 library is to use their default styling? how come my bar chart is not rendering in horizontal lines with their default styles?

Comment: d3 doesn't have default styles for the DOM elements. Have to either do it in the d3.selection.style/attr or using classes/ids and css.

Comment: ah, gotcha! Thanks so much for your help!!